# TypeError this.a.b is undefined

Tags: javascript

Ive gotten an error in my kibana log, saying the following: 
`this.a.b is undefined`. I'm a bit puzzled about the phrasing, as I'm usually getting `cannot read property b of undefined` When its about an undefined property.

The only place where I'm using this property, I'm assigning a value to it: `this.a.b = 'hello'` - could the assignment be the reason for this wording?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you initialize this.a?

Comment: Check if this.a is actually an object. Without seeing your code, it is difficult to interpret what is happening.

Comment: firstly initialize `this.a` like this : `this.a={};this.a.b='hello'`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code:
Write a nullguard like this:

```
if( this && this.a && this.a.b) { /*do stuff*/}
```

With this you make sure, that the element you want to perform an action on is there.

Comment: Seems like one needs `if (this.a) { ... }` only to avoid TypeError.